# jQuery get sum or numbers from strings on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a page with numerous text strings that resemble this:

```
[1 item here]
Blah blah 99 bottles of beer
[2 items here]
blah [9 items here]
```

I'm looking for a way to get the total (12) as a simple alert:

```
the_magic_number= 'me no habla regex'
alert (the_magic_number);
```

Comment: Try `document.body.textContent.match(/\[(\d+) item here\]/g);` to get all matched strings

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Yo no hablo regex".

Comment: @Blender apparently se no hablo Español tambien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper way to do this:

```
var re = /\[(\d+) items? here\]/g,
    sum = 0,
    arr;
while ((arr = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    sum += parseInt(arr[1]);
}
```

Abuse of `replace` function here:

```
var sum = 0;
str.replace(/\[(\d+) items? here\]/g, function ($0, $1) {
    sum += parseInt($1);
    return ''; // Can return anything, since we don't care about the replace
});
```